# Strange ordering in PriorityQueue in Java

Tags: java, collections, priority-queue

I am trying to use priority queue to keep an ordered list of integers. in a simple exaple like this:

```
PriorityQueue<Integer> queue = new PriorityQueue<>();
queue.offer(3000);
queue.offer(1999);
queue.offer(999);
for(Integer i : queue)
    System.out.println(i);
```

This prints

```
999
3000
1999
```

This is not what I am expecting considering natural odering.

I simply want to iterate without removing or adding through the queue (which serves as a sorted list) WITH ordering. Can I still do that in a simple manner?

Comment: Why not use a SortedList or a SortedSet instead?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

PriorityQueue is a collection optimized for finding the tail or head value quickly, using a partially ordered tree structure called heap (look it up on wikipedia). If you pop the elements, they will be ordered. If you want to iterate, use for example a SortedSet instead, which also stores the elements sorted.

Answer (score 4):

This is a very sneaky problem with PriorityQueue: to quote [the Api](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html)

> The Iterator provided in method iterator() is not guaranteed to
>   traverse the elements of the priority queue in any particular order.
>   If you need ordered traversal, consider using
>   Arrays.sort(pq.toArray()).

Use Poll instead to get the head which will be in order